# Call HPDF_SaveToFile() with japanese filename

Tags: c++, windows, libharu

Im trying to save one pdf in path that contains japanese username. In this case, HPDF_SaveToFile is doing crash my app on windows. Any options to compile or other thing? Any idea to support Unicode filenames with libhaur? I not want to create pdf with japanese encode, I want to write pdf with japanese filename.

Comment: Im getting Error_no:1017 when call HPDF_SaveToFile() with japanese path

Comment: You could always try to debug it. Or you can use HPDF_SaveToStream, and give it a stream that is backed by a file with a Japanese name. Or you can save to a file with an English name, then rename it to the Japanese name.

Comment: @RaymondChen If you have a path with japanese username is because user want to save file in this path and you can't change it. The solution is change libharu API to support wchar_t instead of char.

Comment: You can save it to a temporary file called TEMPFILE, and then after that's done, copy TEMPFILE to the final Japanese name.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in Qt. If you use C++, you can use fstream/ofstream(::write). If you use C, you can use fwrite.

```
QFile file(path);
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    HPDF_SaveToStream(m_pdf);
    /* get the data from the stream and write it to file. */
    for (;;)
    {
        HPDF_BYTE buf[4096];
        HPDF_UINT32 siz = 4096;
        HPDF_STATUS ret = HPDF_ReadFromStream(m_pdf, buf, &siz);

        if (siz == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (-1 == file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(buf), siz))
        {
            qDebug() << "Write PDF error";
            break;
        }
    }
}
HPDF_Free(m_pdf);
```

Refrence: [Libharu Usage examples](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Usage-examples)